# Stream Closed IO Exception Java

Tags: java, inputstream, ioerror

I am running the following program and get the Stream Closed IO Error.
but only in the second loop. the first one works fine.
Can anybody please tell me why? (I checked that the file is existing and not empty.)

```
    private static TimerTask perform(){
        //logging on to FTP-Server

            InputStream  in = client.retrieveFileStream("./htdocs/pwiMain/main.txt");
            InputStream pw = client.retrieveFileStream("./htdocs/pwiMain/cred_pwd.txt");
            BufferedInputStream inbf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            String wholeFile = null;
            String[] contents;
            while((bytesRead = inbf.read(buffer)) != -1){
                wholeFile = new String(buffer,0,bytesRead);
            }
            sentPassword = wholeFile.substring(wholeFile.indexOf("#lap"));
            inbf.close();

            inbf = new BufferedInputStream(pw);
            while((bytesRead = inbf.read(buffer)) != -1){ // this is line72 where the error occurrs...
                wholeFile = new String(buffer,0,bytesRead);
            }
            md5hash = wohleFile;
            inbf.close();
            contents = sentPassword.split("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r");
            System.out.println("contents:    " + contents[0] + "   " + contents[1]);

            //check the password


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ioexception");
        } finally {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at com.protonmail.taylor.faebl.development.main.perform(main.java:72)
    at com.protonmail.taylor.faebl.development.main.main(main.java:23)
```

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Is the file handle for the second file held by anyone else besides this method (resource not closed) ?

Comment: no it is only used for this purpose and should be closed after the password check

Comment: Show us the code of client.retrieveFileStream().

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Apache Commons FTPClient, but if this uses the same socket to transfer the InputStream it may sound logical to close the first InputStream before opening the second one (calling retrieveFileStream).

Comment: client.retrieveFileStream() is a method of the apache Commons (org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile)

Comment: I just tried to close the first Filestream before using the second but it didn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You evidently can't have two retrieval streams active at the same time, which isn't surprising. Just reorder your code:

```
private static TimerTask perform(){
    try {
        //logging on to FTP-Server

        InputStream  in = client.retrieveFileStream("./htdocs/pwiMain/main.txt");
        BufferedInputStream inbf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String wholeFile = null;
        String wholeCred = null;
        String[] contents;
        while((bytesRead = inbf.read(buffer)) != -1){
            wholeFile = new String(buffer,0,bytesRead);
        }
        inbf.close();  // ADDED

        InputStream pw = client.retrieveFileStream("./htdocs/pwiMain/cred_pwd.txt");
        BufferedInputStream pwbf = new BufferedInputStream(pw);
        int pwBytesRead; // YOU DON'T NEED THIS, you could reuse the previous one
        byte[] pwBuffer = new byte [1024]; // DITTO
        while((pwBytesRead = pwbf.read(pwBuffer)) != -1){
            wholeCred = new String(pwBuffer,0,pwBytesRead);
        }
        pwbf.close(); // ADDED

        sentPassword =  wholeFile.substring(sentPassword.indexOf("#lap"));
        md5hash = wholeCred;
        contents = sentPassword.split("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r");
        System.out.println("contents:    " + contents[0] + "   " + contents[1]);

        //check the password


    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ioexception");
    } finally {

    }
    return null;
}
```

There's no point or advantage in the way you're doing it now, you're just wasting space, and as you've discovered it doesn't work.

Of course you will then discover that if either of the inputs exceeds one buffer it won't work, but you didn't ask about that.

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested (I have updated the code.)
but i still get the same error...
(Now I reuse the input stream.)
the cred_pwd.txt file is only one line.
the other one is more than one line and should be splitted at the where it is allocated to contents (is that the mistake?)

Comment: Great answer! I never knew it was impossible to retrieve two streams at once.

Comment: @JFreeman It isn't impossible, except with this piece of software apparently.